# Make alarm Clock with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, alarm

I want to make a alarm clock in android and I write this with BroadcastReceiver But I have some problem with that...
I want to start alarm in specified time for example I want start alarm in every 3:50...
but when I am running the App alarming starting too...

There is my code bellow:

Any one could help me:

there is my broadcast Receiver:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.tester.alarmmanager")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Its time!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.entezar);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

And in MainActivity:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StartAlarm(03,50);

    }

public void StartAlarm(int hour, int min){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction("com.tester.alarmmanager");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(),23433,intent,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.v("time picker",calendar.getTime()+"");
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm>kitkat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm<kitkat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And in Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Utility.MyBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tester.alarmmanager"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: No one know the problem???

Answer (score 0):

add after `calendar.getInstance()`

```
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

or check code under this link https://github.com/mrkostua/SmartAlarm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mrkostua/mathalarm/alarms/mathAlarm/AlarmManagerHelper.kt